# How can I pass a button with (this) to 3 functions step by step

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

```js
function modalPublic(funOkName, text, modalId) {
}

function ConfirmItemRemove(btn) {
    modalPublic('DeleteProductInBaskets(' + btn + ')', 'Are you sure?', 'myModal');
}
function DeleteProductInBaskets(btn) {}

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

```html
<button type='button' data-productid='" + currentItem.Id + "' data-typePage='" + typePage + "' onclick='ConfirmItemRemove(this)'>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just pass the `btn` argument to the function in their expecting order.

```js
function modalPublic(funOkName, text, modalId) {
  console.log('From modalPublic ', funOkName.id)
}

function ConfirmItemRemove(btn) {
  console.log(' In ConfirmItemRemove ', btn.id);
  modalPublic(DeleteProductInBaskets(btn, 'Are you sure?', 'myModal'))
}

function DeleteProductInBaskets(btn, arg1, arg2) {
  console.log(' From DeleteProductInBaskets ', btn.id);
  return btn;
}
```

```html
<button type='button' data-productid='" + currentItem.Id + "' data-typePage='" + typePage + "' onclick='ConfirmItemRemove(this)' id='test'>Click</button>
```